# Android push notification via GCM and Urban Airship

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I have implemented and app starting from google gcm client example.
I get an regId, that seem alright, after that when I try to send a push with Urban Airship I put my regId in the APID field, but it appear an error: invalid APID.

Maybe should I use the urban airship example in android to get the apid?

i think that APID and regID its the same thing. Am I right?

Comment: I solved my question. APID from UrbanAirship it's different from regID gcm. So you have to generate your APID with the UrbanAirship .jar library.

Answer (score 0):

```
   PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(PushNotificationPluginIntentReceiver.class);
            String apid = PushManager.shared().getAPID();
            log.info("My Application onCreate - App APID: " + apid);
        }
```

Using this piece of code get the client app id and It will be used for **Test push**